# Creating a form overlaying on click event

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, authentication, overlay

I am trying to get a form overlaid on click using jQuery.

My HTML is:

```
<html>
<head>
<style>
#displaybox {
z-index: 10000;
filter: alpha(opacity=50); /*older IE*/
filter:progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Alpha(opacity=50); /* IE */
-moz-opacity: .50; /*older Mozilla*/
-khtml-opacity: 0.5;   /*older Safari*/
opacity: 0.5;   /*supported by current Mozilla, Safari, and Opera*/
background-color:#000000;  
position:fixed; top:0px; left:0px; width:100%;height:100%;
                     
    color:#FFFFFF;
    text-align:center; vertical-align:middle;
}
</style>
<title>Login and Registration Form with HTML5 and CSS3</title>
    
    
   
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/demo.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/jquery-ui.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/style.css" />
   <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/animate-custom.css" />






 <script>                                
$(function(){
$( '.datepicker' ).datepicker();
})
</script>
<script>
function clicker(){
var thediv=document.getElementById('displaybox');
if(thediv.style.display == "none"){
    thediv.style.display = "";
    thediv.innerHTML = "<div class="container">
     
        
        <section>               
            <div id="container_demo" >
               <a class="hiddenanchor" id="toregister"></a>
                <a class="hiddenanchor" id="tologin"></a>
                
                   <div id="wrapper">

                    <div id="login" class="animate form">
<table>
<tr>
<td>
             
                        <form action="mysuperscript.php" autocomplete="on"> 

                            <h1>Log in</h1> 
                            <p> 
                     <label for="username" class="uname">Username</label><br>
 <input id="username" name="username" required="required" type="text" 
  placeholder="Please Enter Username"/>
                            </p>
                            <p> 
             <label for="password" class="youpasswd"> Your password</label><br>
                                <input id="password" name="password"

 required="required" type="password" placeholder="eg. X8df!90EO" /> 
                            </p>
                            
<p class="login button"><input type="submit" value="Login" class="hidemodal" /> </p>
 <p class="change_link">
Not a member yet ?  <a href="#toregister" class="to_register">Join us</a></p>
</form>

</td>

<td>
<section class="logformside-container"><h1>Log in with</h1> 
<div>
    <span class="button">  
        <a href="#"><img src="images/facebook.png" alt="">Login with facebook</a>  
    </span>  
<br>
    <span class="button">  
    <a href="#"><img src="images/twitter_standing.png" alt="">Login with twitter</a>  
    </span>  
  <br>
    <span class="button">  
        <a href="#"><img src="images/mail.png" alt="">Login with gmail</a>  
    </span>
</div>  
</section>
</td>
</tr>
</table>
</div>







<div id="register" class="animate form">
<form  action="mysuperscript.php" autocomplete="on"> 
<h1> Register on GoodBuy </h1> 
<p> 
<label for="fullnamesignup" class="uname">Full Name</label>
<br>
<input id="usernamesignup" name="namesignup" required="required" type="text"  
placeholder="mysupername690" />
</p>

<p> 
<label for="emailsignup" class="youmail">Your email</label>
<br>
<input id="emailsignup" name="emailsignup" required="required" type="email"  
placeholder="mysupermail@mail.com"/> 
</p>
                            
<p>
<label for="emailsignup" class="youmail" > Date of birth</label>
<br>   
<input class="datepicker" type="text"  name='' size='9' value="" placeholder="mm/dd/
 yyyy" />
</p>

<p> 
<label for="usernamesignup" class="uname">User Name</label>
<br>
<input id="usernamesignup" name="usernamesignup" required="required" type="text"   
placeholder="mysupername690" />
</p>

                            <p> 
  <label for="passwordsignup" class="youpasswd">Your   password </label><br>
  <input id="passwordsignup" name="passwordsignup" required="required" type="password" 
  placeholder="eg. X8df!90EO"/>
                            </p>
                            <p> 
  <label for="passwordsignup_confirm" class="youpasswd">Please confirm your password 
   </label><br>
   <input id="passwordsignup_confirm" name="passwordsignup_confirm" 
   required="required" type="password" placeholder="eg. X8df!90EO"/>
                            </p>
                            <p class="signin button"> 
<input type="submit" value="Sign up"/> 
                            </p>
    <p class="change_link">Already a member ?<a href="#tologin" class="to_register">
     Go and log in </a>
</p>
     </form>
    </div>
                    
     </div>
     </div>  
     </section>
     </div>";
  }
     else{
    thediv.style.display = "none";
    thediv.innerHTML = '';
 }
  return false;
 }
</script>
</head>
<body>
<div id="displaybox" style="display: none;"></div>
<a href='#' onclick='return clicker();'>Open Window</a>
</body>
</html>
```

moto is to show hidden form as when clicked on the link "Open Window".

Answer (score 0):

There are probably syntax errors on this, you need to check for errors on the console.

You're using all double quotes on that html string:

```
thediv.innerHTML = "<div class="container">...</div>";
```

Should be (wrap it with single quotes to form it a correct string):

```
thediv.innerHTML = '<div class="container">...</div>';
```

You need to also trim down that extra line breaks and whitespaces:

```
thediv.innerHTML = '<div class="container"><section><div id="container_demo" ><a class="hiddenanchor" id="toregister">...and so on...';
```

---

Is there any reason why you are setting the contents of 'displaybox' programmatically? You can just simply insert it on the markup and it will be also hidden when you hide the parent container 'displaybox'.

```
<div id="displaybox" style="display: none;">
    <div class="container">
        <section>
            <div id="container_demo" >Contents here..</div>
        <section>
    </div>
</div>
<a href='#'>Open Window</a>
```

And use jQuery, just give `<a>` an id so we can properly use it as a selector:

```
<a href='#' id='open-window'>Open Window</a>
```

jQuery:

```
$('#open-window').click(function (e) {
    //the default of <a> onclick is setting the href, we need to prevent that
    e.preventDefault();
    var thediv = $('#displaybox');
    //check of <div> is hidden/display == none
    if(thediv.is(':hidden')){
        //you can apply some fade animation as well with fadeIn() and fadeOut()
        thediv.show();
    }else{
        thediv.hide();
    }
});
```

See this [**jsfiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/DB4AF/).

Comment: I have tried both.. the modifications suggested by you and also the fiddle... but no luck yet....

Comment: Is the 'displaybox' not shown on click? Can you first check for errors, then just simply try if the click event is firing `$('#open-window').click(function(){ alert('click') /*remove everything inside just try to alert only*/});`

Comment: simply its not working... like the hidden form doesn't appears on click.